# Video files showing up in file input accept=audio attribute

Tags: html, google-chrome, input

I am implementing file upload in my application. I have input elements for different media types.

```
<label>Audios<input type="file" accept="audio/*"/></label>
<label>Videos<input type="file" accept="video/*"/></label>
```

Everything is working fine in Firefox. However, in Chrome webm files are showing up for audio input type. And in IE 3gp files are showing.

Can somebody please explain what's happening here?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in the pop-up, you can choose all files.

Comment: Yes. If we select all files from the dropdown, it will show all files.
But my doubt is why its showing 3gp if we give audio? is it a bug in browser or 3gp is treated as audio in IE?

Comment: Actually, each browser has different implementations, for identifying videos and images. So, on the server-side, you'll have to check if the uploaded file is an image or a video.

Comment: That I am doing anyway, just want to know if there is any reason for this behaviour.

Comment: The problem is that many video formats can also be used to store audio tracks only. (For instance, MPEG files can contain only audio layer III tracks if they want.) So the browser plays it safe and shows the list of all files that can be audio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a possibility that .3gp extension can be used for files containing audio but no
visual presentation, so the browser behaves in that manner only to these files and consider them as audio files. For example we can use the mime type "audio/3gpp" for the files with 3gp extension and have only audio and no visuals.
for reference specifically about 3gpp files you can refer

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3839

and 3gpp is not the only format where you will face this issue, there are other formats too, to which browsers behave differently. Read about other mime types from here.

http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

You can see about all media types from here. Hope this helped.